# How to make first letter of paragraph bigger without stretching the content

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph with some text and I need to make the first letter bigger than the rest, I know how to make it and it works, but the way that I am doing it adds an extra space between the first sentence and the rest of the content:

[image]

How can I make the letter big but without adding this extra space?

```css
.first-word-uppercase-p::first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e80222;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="first-word-uppercase-p">
  There is no doubt that people find out who they really are when their backs are against the wall. Such was the case for Sara Owen, a single mother who found herself without the ability to make ends meet and provide for her three children. "I wasn't broke,
  but times were tough," says Sara, who even found herself having to hide from her landlord on occasion. But everything changed when Sara decided that she was going to take her destiny into her own hands. "I was thinking about investing in stocks for
  several years, but I could never find the courage to do it. Little did I know that I would turn $200 into $2000 in only a matter of days.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `line-height` for that letter and it will close the gap:

```css
.first-word-uppercase-p::first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e80222;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: .75;
}
```

```html
<p class="first-word-uppercase-p">
  There is no doubt that people find out who they really are when their backs are against the wall. Such was the case for Sara Owen, a single mother who found herself without the ability to make ends meet and provide for her three children. "I wasn't broke,
  but times were tough," says Sara, who even found herself having to hide from her landlord on occasion. But everything changed when Sara decided that she was going to take her destiny into her own hands. "I was thinking about investing in stocks for
  several years, but I could never find the courage to do it. Little did I know that I would turn $200 into $2000 in only a matter of days.
</p>
```

Comment: If you are not comfortable with pseudo selector, try using the inline element and style it

Comment: @PrabeshGouli this should probably be a comment on the question and not this answer. Also, the OP is obviously OK with the pseudo selector, since they are using it.

Comment: I know it must be on question, but If I commented that on the question it will not be helpful until I explain about pseudo selector separately and you were giving the perfect answer using pseudo selector so I thought it would be more helpful if I added an alternative here.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach involves the utilization of the [`initial-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter) CSS property to enhance the design.

```css
p:first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e80222;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Initial letter occupies 2 lines and sinks 1 line */
  initial-letter: 2 1;
}

p:nth-of-type(2):first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Initial letter occupies 2 lines */
  initial-letter: 2;
}
```

```html
<p>
  There is no doubt that people find out who they really are when their backs are against the wall. Such was the case for Sara Owen, a single mother who found herself without the ability to make ends meet and provide for her three children. "I wasn't broke,
  but times were tough," says Sara, who even found herself having to hide from her landlord on occasion. But everything changed when Sara decided that she was going to take her destiny into her own hands. "I was thinking about investing in stocks for
  several years, but I could never find the courage to do it. Little did I know that I would turn $200 into $2000 in only a matter of days.
</p>

<p>
While cinema chains in many key markets including the U.S. — already pressured by the rise of streaming services — have struggled to attract patrons back to their padded seats following the lifting of COVID-19 curbs, in Southeast Asia it’s a far more promising picture: Local box office records are being set, filmmaking grants are being unveiled and large cinema chains are shifting into expansion mode.
</p>
```

Comment: Since ``initial-letter`` is not supported by all browsers, `float: left` can be used instead to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score -1):

Set a fixed `line-height` on main element and the first-letter will inherit it. This will work for all the `font-size` configuration

```css
.first-word-uppercase-p {
  line-height:1.2em;
}

.first-word-uppercase-p::first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e80222;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.first-word-uppercase-p.bigger::first-letter {
  font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="first-word-uppercase-p">
  There is no doubt that people find out who they really are when their backs are against the wall. Such was the case for Sara Owen, a single mother who found herself without the ability to make ends meet and provide for her three children. "I wasn't broke,
  but times were tough," says Sara, who even found herself having to hide from her landlord on occasion. But everything changed when Sara decided that she was going to take her destiny into her own hands. "I was thinking about investing in stocks for
  several years, but I could never find the courage to do it. Little did I know that I would turn $200 into $2000 in only a matter of days.
</p>

<p class="first-word-uppercase-p bigger">
  There is no doubt that people find out who they really are when their backs are against the wall. Such was the case for Sara Owen, a single mother who found herself without the ability to make ends meet and provide for her three children. "I wasn't broke,
  but times were tough," says Sara, who even found herself having to hide from her landlord on occasion. But everything changed when Sara decided that she was going to take her destiny into her own hands. "I was thinking about investing in stocks for
  several years, but I could never find the courage to do it. Little did I know that I would turn $200 into $2000 in only a matter of days.
</p>
```